# How do I properly set the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Tags: java, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, environment-variables

Very inexperienced developer here, sorry for ignorance!
Attempting to set up Android Emulator through Android Studio SDK>

I've been on as many threads as I can see about problems setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. 
Some people say use the /bin folder some people don't.
I think I'm missing something to do with the PATH variable but I cannot work out what I haven't done or what I should set the PATH variable to.

How should I properly set the JAVA_HOME environment variable?
What should my PATH look like? Is it the user/system PATH variable?

Command line error:

```
(node:7952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
```

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME should be pointing to the bin folder "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin" If you look closely, bin folder contains your javac.

Comment: Hey @Novice, I've now done that. I've read that I have got to set the System Environment Variable "Path" to the JDK also. I've set it through the GUI when I type the "path" command into cmd, the path I just entered isn't displayed. I've got a feeling my problem is coming from here somewhere. Any advice?

Comment: What OS are you using? Go to system variables and set it. If you want to run your code urgently, instead of building as javac, build as C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/javac

Comment: Quoting from the official page "To set the PATH variable permanently, add the full path of the jdk1.7.0\bin directory to the PATH variable. Typically, this full path looks something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin. Set the PATH variable as follows on Microsoft Windows:Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.
Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.
Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation for the PATH variable in System Variables. Complete link:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html

Comment: I'm on Windows, sorry for omitting that.

Comment: Yeah that's the page I've been following, originally.

Comment: What version of windows ? on Windows 10 You have to right click on my computer, go to "Advanced System Settings" Click on Environment Variables, click on path in system variables and just check if you already have bin mapped, else just add it. Apply and close any command prompt you have open, open it fresh and it should be working. .. Or in start menu, just type environment variables and click on "Edit the system environments", go to environment variables and add it to path.

Comment: Windows 10 yes. I've set up the environment variable in user and added the directory to the beginning of path, but it still has a problem with the JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: That is coz you have not set JAVA_HOME , you have just set path to execute javac, you need to explicitly set JAVA_HOME, preferably in user variables/

Comment: Yeah I've set JAVA_HOME to the bin directory as well, and the path variable includes the JAVA_HOME variable at the beginning.

Comment: JAVA_HOME should not be pointed to bin, it should point to the folder.  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0 and the path should either contain %JAVA_HOME%/bin or the complete path : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin .
JAVA_HOME is a convention used by applications like your app server or certain build tools to find where JAVA resides. Good luck with Java !!